# Convexity of open balls in a metrizable subset of a locally convex t.v.s.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

The following result is well known (Rudin, Functional Analysis, Theorem 1.24): If $X$ is a locally convex topological vector space with a countable local base then there is a compatible metric $d$ such that all open balls are convex.
My question is: Assume that $X$ is a locally convex t.v.s. which is not metrizable and $C$ is a compact, convex and metrizable subset of $X$. Is there a metric compatible with the topology of $C$ such that all open balls are convex?

Answer (score 1):

Let
$
  s: X\times X\to X
  $
be the *subtraction map*, namely
$$
  s(x,y) = x-y, \quad \forall x,y\in  X,
  $$
and put
$$
  D:= s(C\times C) =  \{x-y: x, y\in  C\}.
  $$

We next claim that $D$ is homeomorphic to a quotient of $C\times C$.  Indeed, consider the equivalence relation $R$ on $C\times C$
according to which two points are equivalent iff they have the same image under $s$.   Since $s$ obviously respects $R$,  there is a unique
continuous map
$$
  \tilde s:(C\times C)/{R}\ \to \ D,
  $$
such that $s=\tilde s\circ  q$, where $q$ is que quotient map.

It is not hard to see that $\tilde s$ is a bijective map,
and since $(C\times C)/{R}$ is compact and $D$ is Hausdorff, we conclude that $\tilde s$ is a homeomorphism, thus proving the claim.

[Every Hausdorff quotient of a compact metrizable space is itself metrizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1745722/quotient-of-compact-metric-space-is-metrizable-when-hausdorff), so $D$ is metrizable and hence also   first countable.

Noticing that  $0$ lies in $D$,  we may then find a countable open neighborhood base
for $0$ in the relative topology of $D$,  say  $\{V_n\}_n$.   Write each $V_n$ as $W_n\cap D$,  where $W_n$ is an open subset of
$X$, and choose an open,  convex,  balanced set $U_n$,  with
$$
  0\in U_n\subseteq W_n.
  $$

It is then evident that
$$
  V'_n := U_n\cap D \subseteq  W_n\cap D = V_n,
  $$
so the $V'_n$
form an open neighborhood base for $0$ in the relative
topology of $D$.

For each $n$, let $p_n$ be the Minkowsky functional associated to $U_n$ and consider the (not necessarily
Hausdorff), locally convex topology $\tau'$ on $X$ generated by the $p_n$.

We next claim that $(C, \tau ')$ is Hausdorff.  To see this, let $x$ and $y$ be  distinct points  in $C$,
and notice that
$$
  z:= y-x\in  C-C = D.
  $$
Choose an open set $A\subseteq X$, such that $0\in A$ and
$z\notin A$,  and  let $n$ be such that $V'_n\subseteq  A\cap D$.

Notice that $z\notin U_n$ since otherwise
$$
  z\in  U_n\cap D = V'_n\subseteq  A\cap D\subseteq A.
  $$
It follows that
$$
  1\leq p_n(z)=p_n(y-x),
  $$
so $x$ and $y$ may be separated in the topology generated by $p_n$, and hence also in $\tau '$, proving our
claim.

Clearly $\tau '$ is coarser than the default
topology $\tau $ of $X$,   so the identity  map
$$
  \text{id} : (C, \tau ) \to  (C, \tau ')
  $$
is continuous.

Given that $(C, \tau)$ is compact, and that we now know that $(C, \tau ')$ is Hausdorff, we have that
the above map is a homeomorphism.

In case $(X,\tau ')$ happens to be Hausdorff, an application of the result by Rudin mentioned by the OP would provide the
desired metric, but a slight adaptation of it also works even if $\tau '$ is not Hausdorff.  By that I mean that Rudin's
proof carries through without the assumption that $(X,\tau ')$ is Hausdorff, as long as we drop the
requirement that $d$ satisfies
$$
  d(x,y)=0\Rightarrow x=y,
  $$
that is, as long as we satisfy ourselves with a pseudo-metric, rather than a metric.

The resulting pseudometric $d$ would of course be compatible with the topological space  $(C, \tau ')$, and hence also $(C, \tau )$,
but since this is a Hausdorff space,  as seen above,  $d$ must be a metric when restricted to $C$.

Comment: Dear Ruy, thanks for your help. Here follows two comments. In proving that $D=C-C$ is second countable you use the fact that $s:X\times X\rightarrow X$ is a continuous open map. It seams however that the restriction $s|_C$ of $s$ to $C$ to be open is needed. Since in general the restriction of an open map is not open, is $s|_C$ open, that is, if $U_1$ and $U_2$ are open in $C$, is the difference $U_1-U_2$ open in $C-C$? The second comment concerns the metrizability of $(X,\tau^\prime)$ that you use at the end of the proof. As you correctly noted, this space is not necessarily Hausdorff!

Comment: Giulio, you are right that there is a problem with my argument regarding 2nd countability of $D$.  A better argument is that $D$ is a Hausdorff image of a compact metrizable space, hence itself compact metrizable.  Regarding your second point, you must ignore that $\tau'$ is not Hausdorff, but also don't require that a metric must satisfy $d(x,y)=0\Rightarrow x=y$, and proceed as usual.

Comment: I'll edit my answer to account for this as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

$Y=\operatorname{span}(C)$ is a locally convex tvs which is still metrisable I think (using that $C$ has a countable base, being compact metrisable). So the first result would apply there.

Comment: I am not sure either, but metrizability of span$(C)$ sounds like a long shot to me.

Comment: @Ruy do you have a counterexample then?

Comment: No.  As I said, I'm not sure either.

Comment: I think that the metrizability of span$(C)$ does not work. For instance, if $X$ is a separable Banach space, then the unit ball in $X^*$ is compact and metrizable in the weak$^*$ topology but the dual space $X^*$ is not metrizable.